# Openlayers 4 ScaleLine not visible

Tags: openlayers

I am debugging a problem in an openlayers-based map application. Some time ago the ScaleLine control stopped being shown and I cannot find why. In the code below, if I change the units to degrees, the ScaleLine will show up as expected but for any other of the accepted units (us, metric, imperial, etc.) the ScaleLine will not be rendered.

Code that creates the ScaleLine:

```
var scaleLine = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
        target: document.getElementById('map-scale-bar'),
          units: "metric",
          minWidth: 100
      });
      map.addControl(scaleLine);
```

The target div looks like this after being rendered:

```
<div id="map-scale-bar" data-reactid=".0.2.0">
<div class="ol-scale-line ol-unselectable" style="display: none;">
<div class="ol-scale-line-inner">
</div></div></div>
```

Does anyone have any hint for why the ScaleLine will only be shown for degrees?

Comment: ScaleLine control works fine in any case. check this fiddle to test it --> https://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/phjf318y/ . Better make a fiddle with your own code to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I checked in my browser and i found that i have <div class="ol-scale-line-inner" style="width: 79px;">1000 m</div> and the value inside is changing as well but i do not see anything on the map itself ?